# How to effectively/properly use IntPtr in ImGui.NET

Tags: c#, .net, imgui

How should I go about using methods that take an `IntPtr` in the .NET Dear ImGui wrapper, ImGui.NET?

For example, `ImGui.SetDragDropPayload` takes a type `string`, an `IntPtr`, and a size `unint`. When I `ImGui.GetDragDropPayload()` I don't seem to be able to just grab the type that I set (I can only query if it is a certain type)... And I'm not sure how to use `IntPtr` to represent an object in my game engine, which I presume is one of the use cases this parameter is intended for.

I feel like there is a fundamental paradigm that I'm not understanding here, as using `IntPtr` to hold game data seems like a common thing in ImGui.NET. I've done some looking into how to represent objects as `IntPtr` in .Net, but this seems to point me to creating `IntPtr` for use in WinApi functions and I haven't been able to get anything working yet or understand how I should be approaching this...

As you can probably tell, I'm also entirely unfamiliar with the C++ Dear ImGui, so this makes things even trickier for me to get my head around. Any thoughts would be appreciated!

***Edit:***

Here's an example of how I'm using it right now. As I mentioned, I don't know how to use the payload propertly, so I'm just using a separate static object to represent what's currently being dragged. Then checking to see if the payload's NativePtr is null or not. It seems to work, I think, but is obviously not ideal:

```
private static unsafe void SubmitTestWindow()
{
    ImGui.Begin("Test");

    string[] items = new string[] { "hello", "world", "how", "are", "you?" };

    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        ImGui.Button(items[i]);
        if (ImGui.BeginDragDropSource())
        {
            ImGui.Text(items[i]);
            ImGui.SetDragDropPayload(typeof(string).FullName, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
            draggedItem = items[i];
            ImGui.EndDragDropSource();
        }
        if (ImGui.BeginDragDropTarget())
        {
            var payload = ImGui.AcceptDragDropPayload(typeof(string).FullName);
            if (payload.NativePtr != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dropped " + draggedItem + " onto " + items[i]);
                draggedItem = null;
            }
            ImGui.EndDragDropTarget();
        }
    }

    ImGui.End();
}
```